# How to achieve mysql WHERE IN in CouchBase?

Tags: couchbase, sql++, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am trying to search my documents of specific type which have specific id's. But I have id's in an array. I could do that easily in MySQL using WHERE IN clause. But how to do that in CouchBase?

My Query may look like this -

```
SELECT token
FROM default
WHERE type = 'type1'
AND id IN ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
```

Comment: @JerodJohnson thanks! got it!

Comment: this query should work. N1QL supports both IN and WITIN.